# How to search for a file on users file system? ( Adobe Air application)

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, air, mxml

So we want to seacrch for file like exampl*.ex*mple. We want to search in all users files and folders.

I know it will take long, but steel using ONLY AS3\MXML, no native commands, no external programms - only AS3\MXML libs and classes, we can skeep all folders with sise <= 200kb

So How to search for a file on users file system? (in Air application, NOT NATIVE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look on this [sample](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Asynchronously_searching_for_files_of_a_given_exte-9383.html). You will have to modify it in order to add your special conditions, but it's very easy.

Comment: Nice Component.  Can we modify this component to achieve following.

1. Content search : I type in some content and it returns me the list of files which actually have "content" inside.

2. Expand component to search over LAN.